# unique_ptr with standard containers: attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use unique_ptr with any stl container (actually list is prefer for me), I see that unique_ptr requires move semantics .
this code where employee is a base class:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<employee> p_employee;

std::list<p_employee> make_test_array() {
    std::list<p_employee> objects = {
       p_employee(new accounter(...)),
       p_employee(new engineer(...)),
       p_employee(new developer(...))
    };

    return objects;
}
```

you see what I'm trying to do - just a return this list from a function

so is there ability to do this? what is a right technique?

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to construct the `std::list<p_employee>` using the `std::list` constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list<p_employee>` argument.

Unfortunately, `std::initializer_list` only allows `const` access to its elements, which means the compiler will try to copy each `p_employee` (or `std::unique_ptr<employee>`) which fails because a `unique_ptr` is a move-only type and cannot be copied.

Your code should work if you replace the *braced-init-list* with a series of `emplace_back`/`push_back` calls.

```
std::list<p_employee> make_test_array() {
    std::list<p_employee> objects;

    objects.emplace_back(new accounter(...));
    objects.push_back(p_employee(new engineer(...))); // the exception safe alternative
    // and so on

    return objects;
}
```

Comment: @T.C. I thought about it, but was being lazy to edit. Should've known someone would call me out on that :)

Comment: thanks a lot, I know about correct constructing in-place,
but have read the error wrongly - I believed that error message was generated on the line "    return objects;          ".                                                                           How would you do the same for std:array ?

Comment: @amigo421 `std::array` is an aggregate, so you can use braces to perform the initialization as in your original example because in this case it would be aggregate initialization, and no copying of `unique_ptr`s will be attempted. Alternatively, you can default construct the `unique_ptr`s in the `array` and then use `unique_ptr::reset` or its move assignment operator to add elements - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f71df479b4124f3